# Creating a PopUp Slider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to have an input box for numeric values, with clickable triangle on right (*similar to a combo box*).  When you click on the triangle, a slider appears below the input box, and you can drag the knob on the slider to adjust the value in the input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I am able to figure out why wasn't the new panel displaying. You need to replace a line in the code in the previous answer. You need to replace:

```
NSPanel *newWindow = [[[NSPanel alloc]initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:NSUtilityWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]autorelease];
```

With

```
NSPanel *newWindow = [[[NSPanel alloc]initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:NSUtilityWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]retain];
```

The problem was the `newWindow` got released each time before the user was able to see it. So, basically we needed to retain the `newWindow`.

Comment: Although I was able to create the panel, Now I want this panel to be displayed at the space over the _downward arrow_ of the button. How can this be done?